# cakephp 3 showing blank on server

Tags: cakephp, web-hosting

I have uploaded cakephp application on hosting server. But it is showing blank page.

I have uploaded website in

```
/root/site/
```

and using PHP version 7.

Content of `.htaccess` in `/root/site/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

But I'm getting error 404.
**server log**

```
43.225.0.196 - - [13/Aug/2016:23:28:44 -0400] "GET /site/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1363 website.com "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0" "-"
```

sometimes it shows blank page

domain path to the application is

```
http://website.com/site
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try replacing the cakePHP application with just a Hello-World page, does it work then? If it does not, the problem is not related to your application.

Also, is the directory `/root/site` added to your webserver? (Are you using Apache?)

And lastly, is url rewriting properly enabled in the webserver?